# Shuffle a specific rows in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows, shuffle

I have this dataframe `df`:

```
col1  col2  col3
673   89279 902
893   894   897
083   37    23
94    382   342
```

And I need to randomaly shuffle the rows except the first one, any help with that please?

Comment: No, in that post is how to shuffle the all dataframe rows, here I want to specify range of rows (from 2nd to the end, i.e all except the first row) @ChristianSloper

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
df = pd.concat([df[:1], df[1:].sample(frac=1)]).reset_index(drop=True)
```